# Using .bat file to run coded UI tests, how do I specify which coded ui test to run?

Tags: batch-file, coded-ui-tests

I do know how run coded ui tests using a windows .bat file. It's relatively straight forward. You download MS Test Agent [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents) and just use the relevant link for VS 2017 or VS 2015. In your coded ui project, select Build -> Batch Build. Copy the dll and make a .bat file that references your coded ui dll.

My .Bat file looks like this:

```
C:

cd codedui

set mstestPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE"

%mstestpath%\mstest /testcontainer:AppUnderTestCodedUITesting.dll
```

For reference, the steps are covered in better detail [here](http://codeduiadda.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/how-to-schedule-microsoft-coaded-ui.html).

My question is this: How do I run just 1 test using my .bat file? The problem is that using the approach described, all of my tests run. Of course I have hundreds of small tests (each test typically clicks 1 button or does 1 small thing). I don't want to run all those small tests, I want to 1 and only 1 ordered test. How do I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, after a bit of head scratching I found the answer myself. I just had to add the /test option. So my test line is now:

```
%mstestpath%\mstest /testcontainer:SynTQCodedUITesting.dll /test:common_test_A
```

Where "common_Test_A" is the name of my test. I still don't know how to specify an ordered test but with a bit of a change in my coded ui project, I can make a test that runs all the tests I need in the order I want which is a bit like an ordered test.

If anyone happens to know how to specify an ordered test instead of a test, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not validate, but did you try to create an [ordered test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx) then use the ordered test file as [testcontainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testcontainer):

> The test container is a file that contains the tests you want to run. For example, for ordered tests, the test container is the .orderedtest file that defines the ordered test.

If this method does not work, you can declare the tests to run by separating them with a comma:

```
%mstestpath%\mstest /testcontainer:SynTQCodedUITesting.dll /test:common_test_A,comm_test_B
```

But they won't be ordered. I believe MSTest will play them depending the class and method's names.

I think you should not run all your tests from one main test. If one test fail, then the main test will also fail (without exception management) and all further tests won't be played. You should use TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods to make your tests independent from each others.

Granularity is also the key when debugging your tests.